# c++ - using std namespace and dependancies

Tags: c#, c++, c++11

While trying to familiarize myself with c++ and its concepts, I came across the

```
using namespace std
```

and

```
#include <iostream>
```

my simple code is as follows

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ConsoleApplication5.h"
#include <iostream>     

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hi";
    return 0;
}
```

Using Visual Studio 2015 Community, which uses intellisense, shows

> cout

uses the following

> std::ostream std::cout

As a C# programmer, this confuses me slightly. Is this :

> std::ostream

being a return type while

> std::cout

being the method/parameter passed or is

> std::ostream

a dependancy of

> cout

**UPDATE** (after Archimaredes Answer)

In C#, one can use the following:

```
StreamWriter srWrite;
```

or

```
StreamWriter srWrite = new StreamWriter(string filepath)
```

or one can use:

```
StreamWriter srWrite = new StreamWriter(new NetworkStream(Socket.GetStream()));
```

Each case a object of type namely

```
StreamWriter
```

is assignable with a new object or a existing file or a networkstream.

I tried the same after that which you mentioned (excuse the C# mentality) with the `std::ostream x = new std:ostream` which returns a no default constructor.

Could you just add how std::ostream and std::cout relate to each other, which creates/initalizes the other. THis concept is still a bit vague to me.

Comment: std::ostream x = new std:ostream() cannot work in either case, as new std:ostream will return a pointer, std:ostream*. Furthermore, there is no default constructor (w/o arguments), so you have to use std::ostream x(streambuf* sb) or std::ostream* x = new std:ostream(streambuf* sb)

Comment: try this : `operator<<(cout,"hi");`

Comment: If you have a second question, please post it as another question. Don't hijack an existing question after somebody has already answered it.

Comment: You don't need to use `new` to create objects in C++ (you _can_ do, but it means something different). If you're trying to familiarize yourself with C++ then I suggest you read a book or a tutorial, not just try to apply your knowledge of a quite different language to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) is an object in global scope, of type [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream). When you call `std::cout << "hi"`, you are invoking the [`operator<<()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) method with the `std::cout` object as your left-hand value and the string literal `"hi"` as the right-hand value.

`cout` and `ostream` are inside the `std` namespace, hence the `std::` prefix. If you place `using namespace std` in your code, this allows you to omit the prefixes, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "hi"; // no error because the 'std' is unnecessary now
}
```

Namespaces are used to prevent name conflicts, in exactly the same way as C#; it is usually good practice to **not** use `using namespace` directives for entire source code files in order to prevent name conflicts in your code.

---

**Edit in response to OP's update**

`std::cout` is an **instance** of `std::ostream`. To illustrate this, consider the following:

```
class A_Class {
public:
    A_Class() {}
    void foo() {}
};

int main() {
    A_Class an_instance;
    an_instance.foo();
}
```

`A_Class` is a class, while `an_instance` is an instance of `A_Class`.

Similarly; `ostream` is a class, while `cout` is an instance of `ostream`.

---

**Edit in response to OP's comments**

This may look confusing to a user of C#, but it is the exact same concept as:

```
int n = 5;
```

Where`int` is the type, and `n` is the variable name.

Comment: @AngelusMortis Most overloads of `std::operator<<` are members of `std::basic_ostream`, but you are correct for the case of the `const char *` overload, yes.

Comment: @Archimaredes apologies, I know my answer lies in what you posted but I do not understand it, could you edit your answer with a small section underneath just using a simple exmple of how the two matches together. It would help me (and anyone else) understand the concept, thanks

Comment: @Archimaredes and by two  meaning "std::ostream ; std::cout", if possible in C# terminology if you are familiar

Comment: @KGCybeX What you're asking to explain requires quite large text to explain how streams work in C++, I'd request you to read thinking in C++, chapter streams, it has good explanation

Comment: @AngelusMortis I think you mightr have just solved all my c++ problems :p thanks!

Comment: @KGCybeX "std::ostream" is the name of a type. "std::cout" is the name of a variable. It's possible that some of your confusion is caused by C# not having global variables. In C#, you would use a static member variable of a class instead.

Comment: @KGCybeX I made an edit, in case that helps. (And fixed it.)

Comment: @Archimaredes so what you are saying 'std::ostream std::cout' is the same as 'string newLine' or 'int xyz'?

Comment: @KGCybeX Yes, I suppose - but you do not create `std::cout` yourself. `std::cout` is a **global** variable. You do not create it yourself. It is defined in the standard library.

Comment: @Archimaredes thank you, thank you, thank you! This makes complete sense, I could slove any problem in the work now :p. Do me a favour, add this to your answer, ( class ) std::ostream ( instance of class - name of variable ) std::cout like " string newString " or " int number_to_use ", this helped me understand the concept. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

There are some basic differences between C++ and C#. One of them is initialization syntax.

In C#, if you want to create a new type U which either equals or is derived from a type T, you generally write:

```
T t = new U();
```

For value-types (such as structs), you can also write just:

```
T t;
```

Secondly, there's the issue of object lifetime. With reference-types, their lifetime is, generally (excluding garbage collection/finalization, for simplicity), the duration between the point they're created to the point they're inaccessible from anywhere in the program. With value-types, it's the same thing, except that value-types aren't garbage-collected by themselves: they either "vanish" when their defining stack frame returns, or when the reference-type object of which they form part of the memory is "dead."

With C++, it's a different story.

Loosely speaking, you have "raw" types, which are to some extent equivalent to value-types in C#. Then you have pointers and references, which point to such types. There are much better accounts of what's going on here, but I'm trying to explain just enough background to answer your question.

So, if you hypothetically (assuming all types are defined) typed:

```
StreamWriter sr;
```

in C++, you'd essentially be constructing a new `StreamWriter` object, using its default constructor. Hence, the definition is well-formed only if `StreamWriter` *has* an accessible default constructor in that context.

If you typed:

```
StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter();
```

You would get a compilation error, because `new StreamWriter()` returns a *pointer* to a `StreamWriter`, which you're trying to assign to an "actual" `StreamWriter`.

The correct way to type this (excluding best-practices for now), would be

```
StreamWriter* sr = new StreamWriter();
```

The important difference between "raw" types and pointers (or references) is indirection. Let's consider what would happen in the following function:

```
void func() {
    StreamWriter sr = StreamWriter();
}
```

In this case, the stack frame for `func()` would actually need to consume enough memory to contain the whole contents of a `StreamWriter` instance. That is, if it contained 4 32-bit integers as private members, then the stack frame would have to consume at least 16 bytes (4 * (32 / 8)).

So if you wanted to access a member of `StreamWriter`, there wouldn't be any indirection. You would just read the memory at the offset of that member from the address of your `sr` variable, because `&sr` denotes the start of the actual `StreamWriter` object memory. The implication is that the variable `sr` can only *safely* contain `StreamWriter`, and no derived classes, since those derived classes might require more memory.

This is why I said "raw" types are somewhat equivalent to C# value types, because they share this behavior. If you hadn't noticed it before, C# structs cannot be inherited, and this should also serve to explain, or imply, why that is so.

Now, in the case of the following function, using pointers:

```
void func() {
    StreamWriter* sr = /*...*/;
}
```

Then, conceptually (excluding compiler optimizations in eligible cases), if you wanted to access a certain member of `sr`, you would have to take the following steps:

1. Read the pointer value of `sr`.
2. Infer the desired member variable offset.
3. Add the result of (1) with the result of (2) to get the address of the member variable contained in that specific `StreamWriter` instance, or `sr`.
4. Read the number of bytes corresponding to the size of that member variable, starting from the value obtained from (3).

And the crucial point here, is that there's an indirection. So if `sr` now pointed to a *derived* class of `StreamWriter`, then its basic memory layout would start out just like `StreamWriter`'s, making the previous function still work correctly. This, by the way, is why polymorphism requires you to use either pointers or references. There's an added level of virtual calls and how that works, but that's a bit out of scope for now.

By now you should realize why

1. `std::ostream s = new std::ostream()` is ill-formed.
2. `std::ostream s = std::ostream()` *or* simply `std::ostream s` wouldn't work—because `std::ostream` has no accessible default constructor.

What's missing, though, is that my (2) here seems to conflict with your observing:

```
std::ostream std::cout
```

And that's because that observation misses a crucial modifier in the actual one, which is:

```
extern std::ostream std::cout; // note 'extern'
```

Now, that's not a *definition*, rather it's a *declaration*, that—somewhere—there's an initialized variable in the namespace `std` called `cout` which is of type `ostream`, and we leave it to the linker to figure out *where*, while still being able to make use of that variable.

This is hardly a minimal answer to your question, but I felt like you might benefit from a slightly deeper analysis. Enjoy learning C++!

P.S. I touched on several aspects here which really deserve more attention in and of themselves, as far as proper *usage* goes. However, that would make this answer even longer.

Comment: +std::placeholders::_1, I feel the spirit of teaching in this answer :)

Comment: +1 :) though your (2) near the bottom for one of the illegal examples should read `std::ostream s = std::ostream()`